# how to create a hibernate projection that searches one column for any value = true

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a hibernate entity Type like so

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "type")
public class Type {
  @Column(name = "enabled")
  private boolean enabled = false;
}
```

and I want to create a function that returns if any row in the Type table has enabled = true.  I want to be as efficient as possible by using a projection or criterion but I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the most efficient way to do this is to search for the first row that has `enabled = true`, and check if it exists.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Type.class);
crit.setProjection(Projections.id());
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("enabled", true));
crit.setMaxResults(1);
boolean anyIsEnabled = crit.uniqueResult() != null;
```

The query should return result when/if it encounters the first result with `enabled = true`, so it doesn't have to go through the whole table like a solution using `count`, for example, would have to.

Comment: thanks, can you just explain the query.uniqueResult() and how that runs the query? the examples I am looking at seem to do crit.list() where you have that

Comment: ok cool I see your edit, can you tell me the difference between uniqueResult() and list()

Comment: Sorry, it should've been `crit.uniqueResult()` instead of `query.uniqueResult()`. Anyway, `list()` returns all matching results, while `uniqueResult()` return single result, or null if nothing is found. It throws exception if there are multiple results, but in this case it is not a problem because of `setMaxResults(1)`.